# Why does Blockchain (the company) open source their code but not license it?

Tags: blockchain

I'm very curious as to why Blockchain (the company) doesn't license their open source software. Also, does this mean we (the public) can just use their software and license it using Apache's 2.0 license?

David

Comment: What specific code are you talking about?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to create my own wallet and I now reallize that the V3-Frontend, calls back to the V3-Wallet (core) code. I want to modify and reduce the wallet's functionality and have it's look-feel be my UI changes. I do however want to use the bitcoin core wallet code (V3-Wallet) for whatever I produce as a wallet for the public to use with BTC. I'm really just curious why the company (Blockchain) would host their code openly without an open source license.

Comment: They do. For example, [here](https://github.com/blockchain/My-Wallet-V3/blob/c0bf5615c862fb8d7ec5e3f5031c2998b8ddc690/package.json) you can see that this piece uses an ISC license. Without a license, you couldn't even creatively modify the code.

Answer (score 1):

If they haven't put a license, it means it is "All rights reserved" You can refer to these questions about it:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007674/whats-the-default-license-of-code-published-at-github

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148146/open-source-code-with-no-license-can-i-fork-it

https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1720/what-can-i-assume-if-a-publicly-published-project-has-no-license

It probably means "You can use it for yourself, and for small projects. However, if we want, we may shut down all your projects containing our code."